# Refreshing the printer memory everytime

Tags: javascript, php, zebra-printers, zpl

I am developing a desktop application using `php` and `javascript`. I need to print the image and data of a person who enters the premises using the printer Zebra GC420t printer.

The problem I am facing is - for example lets say A is entering to the premises I take details from him and print the data and his image. When B enters the premises when I try to print the data of B's is printed properly but the image printed is A's image and again I need to give the print to print the B's image.

So this is what happens to my application. Is there any solution to overcome this problem

I referred this [php code](https://gist.github.com/thomascube/9651d6fa916124a9c52cb0d4262f2c3f) that RGB image converting to grf image and the below `javascript` code to send the data to the printer

```
    function sendData(photoURL)
{

    var test;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db/zpl.php?photo='+photoURL,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
            test=data;
            console.log("From ZPL:"+data);

            }

        });
    var mob="",lap="",other="";
    if($("#emobile").val()==="on"){
        mob="Mobile";
    }

    if($("#elaptop").val()==="on"){
        lap="Laptop";
    }

    if($("#eother").val()==="on"){
        other="Other";
    }

    showLoading("Printing...");
    checkPrinterStatus( function (text){
        if (text == "Ready to Print")
        {

        selected_printer.send("^XA N ^XZ");

        selected_printer.send("~DYE:SAMPLE.GRF,A,GRF,5000,030"+test+",A");

     selected_printer.send("^XA^FX ^CFA,30 ^FO100,50^FDVisitor Name:"+$("#user").val()+"^FS ^FO50,80^FDCompany:"+$("#compName").val()+"^FS  ^FO50,110^FDTo Meet:"+$("#toMeet").val()+"^FS ^FO50,150^FDPurpose:"+$("#reason").val()+"^FS ^FO50,190^FDAuthorise^FS ^FO50,220^FDto Carry:"+mob+" "+lap+"^FS ^FO500,70^XG R:SAMPLE.GRF,1,1^FS^XZ");

        }
        else
        {
            printerError(text);
        }
    });
};
```

The above is the `javascript` function which takes the image from the `php` code and send it the function and `selected_printer.send()` is responsible for sending the data to the printer

```
function registration(){

          var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("registration"));
                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'db/registration.php',
                        data: data,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data) {
                          console.log("registration URL: "+data);
                           sendData(data);                                                               
                        }

                    });
```

The `sendData()` is called in the above function

Comment: What initially calls `sendData`, and with what value?  Is it sending the old photoURL?

Comment: yeah. It takes the url of the image and send it to the `php` code to convert. I have a separate `javascript` reference for `sendData`

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I was asking about what calls the function you posted above and what are the values it is passed.  I.E, something is doing `sendData(photoURLdata);`.  What are the values of `photoURLdata` when that happens?  Easy way to see is to add a `console.log(photoURL);` as the first line of `sendData`.  It appears to either be that the same last value for `photoURL` is sent to `sendData` again, OR your ajax call is returning the same `data` for a different url.  Do you understand?

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you check the question @DrewReese

Comment: The string to send the image to the printer doesn't look right. 
 "~DYE:SAMPLE.GRF,A,GRF,5000,030"+test+",A"  I think "GRF" should be just "G" and it looks like you're adding your data string to the "bytes per row" parameter. Those should be separated with a comma I think. And get rid of that last ",A" part. Read through the zebra ZPL Command guide for the "~DY" command. You may also want to try erasing the image file when you are done with it. Not sure how the over-writing works.